# Show GoogleMaps on View in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

My code:

```
var camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(currentLocation.latitude, longitude: currentLocation.longitude, zoom: 12) 
//latitude, longitude like :31.230416 and 121.473701.
let map = GMSMapView(frame: CGRectZero)
map.delegate = self
map.camera = camera
self.view = map
```

It work fine! like this:

[image]

But when I create new View: `@IBOutlet weak var mapView: UIView!`

Then change this line: `self.view = map` to `self.mapView = map`

It not work for me, I get a blank view.

Comment: Great question and answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I fixed it by go to my view (view display map), then change class my view to GMSMapView. 
[image]