# GMS Map View always showing Europe

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios, gmsmapview

I'm trying to use Google Maps SDK to display a map of my current location (Berkeley, CA) as the focus, but regardless of what lat/lon I put in, it always shows Europe, as shown below:

[image]

Here is the code for the map view:

```
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(37.8750360, longitude: -122.2573240, zoom: 1)
    mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)
    mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
    mapView.delegate = self
```

I'm doing very similar things in other parts of my application, but have never gotten an issue. If someone knows how to fix this, please let me know! Thanks

Comment: make sure you are not overwriting latitude and longitude

Comment: @Sampath Duddu i'm having the same exact issue. How did you fix this?

Comment: same here since ages. tell me how did you resolve it please.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you are test on real device. not be Simulator,
If you use Simulator than enter latitude and longitude manually.

Like this-

[image]

Comment: The thing is that I am not using current location. I'm using a specific location and it is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can test is on simulator as well and you can change location without enter lat-long
for that you need to change location from your Xcode (above console Please rifler the below screen shot

[image])

Comment: Yes, but I am not using my current location. I am using a specific location with a specific lat and lon.

Comment: Then you need to enter manully lat-long on simulator or you can set it in code as default location

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is because you are setting the mapView's frame to [`CGRectZero`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22217964/can-any-one-please-explain-what-is-use-of-cgrectzero). This may cause the map to have zero height and zero width.

Example based from this [tutorial](http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/google-maps-mobile-sdk-using-swift#sthash.61Rt2LYq.dpuf):

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
let camera: GMSCameraPosition = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(37.8750360, longitude: -122.2573240, zoom: 1)
mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(self.view.frame, camera: camera)
mapView.camera = camera
}
```

Check these related questions:

- [Current Location in Google Maps with swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34956217/current-location-in-google-maps-with-swift)
- [Show GoogleMaps on View in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32431411/show-googlemaps-on-view-in-swift)

Answer (score 0):

You're setting up your view before even setting your delegate (so your code isn't even attached to your instance of mapView). Fix it like this:

1: Make sure you've defined your `GMSMapViewDelegate` for the class

2: Set your delegates first

```
mapView.delegate = self
mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(37.8750360, longitude: -122.2573240, zoom: 1)
mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)
```